# API returning error while performing a POST

Tags: php, json, api, post, postman

I am doing a test and need to POST at a particular endpoint.

The endpoint is: `http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create`

According to the documentation (http://dummy.restapiexample.com/create) a JSON of the form `{"name": "test", "salary": "123", "age": "23"}` is required .

However, when I use Postman software to perform POST, exactly passing JSON above, an error 500 is returned.

Am I doing something wrong, forgetting something, or is it an API problem?

Following error returned below:

[image: Error 505]

**[EDIT]**

This is my Postman request:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of what it looks like in Postman? What does the request body look like? What Headers did you use? You currently just have an app error without any context.

Comment: I edited the post including the images. It's correct?

Comment: Yeah that's better, it's a basic request so and if the POST body was incorrect, it would probably return a 4XX error but as its returning a 500 code and stating its  a problem with an internal function for `checkRecord()` - It's more that likely the API

Answer (score 0):

Did you check following things in Postman client?

1. Type of body field ? Check for 'raw' field.
2. Check the drop-down and select appropriate input type like application/json, xml etc. I hope you want `JSON(application/json)`
   [image]

Comment: That's a older version of Postman so it would look a little bit different now. Params have moved and the label would say JSON, in the drop down.

Comment: @DannyDainton My request is anyway, look at the images I included in the question.

Comment: @galloleonardo: As it is error `500`, which is Internal server error. Hence, as what Danny said, the problem is in your implementation and logic somewhere. May be you go through the Trace and userdefined function once again

Comment: @OmPrakashSao, Thanks! The API is not mine, I just need to consume it. I will notify the owner, thanks again!